# Decomposition of measures as a product measures

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X\times Y$ be a measurable space and $\mu$ be a measure on $X\times Y$.

I am trying to decompose $\mu$ into a product measure. Is the following a valid decomposition?

$$
\mu(A\times B)=\nu(A)\times \bar\mu(B)
$$
where $\nu(A)=\mu(A\times Y)$ and $\bar\mu(B)=\mu(X\times B)$ (that is, $\nu$ and $\bar\mu$ are projections of $\mu$).

My gut feeling is no. But I am not sure what the reasoning might be.

(The end goal is to be use some Fubini type argument to reduce a certain expression.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=Y=\{0,1\}$. We can define the measure by what it does to points. Let $\mu(0,0)=\mu(0,1)=\mu(1,0)=1/3$ and $\mu(1,1)=0$. Clearly, this measure can not be written as a product. If we are talking about probabilities, the argument is that when the marginals are not stochastically independent, the probability on $Y$ given a point in $X$ will depend on the point.